# eCobertura does not respect @CoverageIgnore

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, cobertura, ecobertura

The eCobertura plugin for eclipse seams to ignoge the @CoverageIgnore tag. Classes or methods marked with the tag are still shown red and are counted as untested code in the coverage statistics.

Any ideas to get the @CoverageIgnore tags working?

[image]

Comment: I had a bad experience using eCobertura many years ago. EclEmma is a better option IMO

Comment: EclEmma has no ignore tag. Excluding via regex is not an option.